# Retrieve Data from Index Itself?

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

I have the following query in MySQL:

```
SELECT sid, date
FROM table
WHERE wid = 12938248 AND url = 'example.com/landingpage'
```

Provided that I have an index as such:

```
 CREATE INDEX testindex ON table (wid,url,sid,date)
```

Will MySQL be able to retrieve **sid, date** from the index itself, or will it need to access the disk?

Thanks!

Comment: The index is on disk just as much as the table is, so "it need to access the disk"

Comment: Add `EXPLAIN` to the front of the query and mysql will tell you if it can

Comment: Hmm, which column in EXPLAIN tells me that? It says it's a RANGE type query and is going through 4212 rows

Comment: You will see `Using index` in the extra column

Comment: Hmm, it says Using where, and not Using index. Does this mean it's reading the actual row and not satisfied with the index itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can retrieve data using only the index.

Yes it will still need to access the disk as that is where the index lives.

Comment: Ah, okay. But since it can get the answer from the index itself, it's still as fast as it can be, right?

Comment: Depends if mysql decides that it can get the result with a covering index or not, changing the order of the where clause may throw off the mysql optomizer

Comment: How do I know what the right order is? I've been trying to use EXPLAIN SELECT to judge the query's performance.

Comment: It may change depending if you use MyISAM or InnoDB (not the same way of calculating cardinality of index), and the size of the table. For example a very short table may be accessed by a simple table scan, even if index exists.

Comment: IIRC, the general rule is to put the most discriminating columns first in the index?

Comment: This is a large table (~7GB) with 6 million rows and uses InnoDB.

Comment: @xd44 Actually if the column order does not match the order in the index than a covering index may not be possible as far as the optimizer if concerted

Comment: @AdrianCornish by column order do you mean the order in my SQL statement or the order in which the columns appear in the table structure>

Comment: @xd44 Sorry should have been more clear - it can be in many place, but for example if the `WHERE` clause columns were reversed it could confuse the optimizer and get it to pick a different index which could not satisfy the `SELECT` columns

Comment: Ah, okay I'll look out for that!